# Вопрос по микро и макрозадачам. Event loop

Tags: javascript, event-loop

Вопрос из https://learn.javascript.ru/event-loop

```
setTimeout(function timeout() {
    console.log('Таймаут');
}, 0);

let p = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    console.log('Создание промиса');
    resolve();
});

p.then(function(){
    console.log('Обработка промиса');
});

console.log('Конец скрипта');
```

learn js пишет что правильный ответ:

```
Создание промиса
Конец скрипта
Обработка промиса
Таймаут
```

но.  почему так? Ведь сначала выполняются обычные задачи, потом по приоритету микро и потом макро. Должно же быть

```
Конец скрипта
Создание промиса
Обработка промиса
Таймаут
```

Можете разьяснить?(

Comment: Так создание `!==` выполнение. А то что функция, переданная конструктору, вызывается сразу, [сказано здесь](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), поэтому `console.log` и вызывается в той же строке без всяких очередей и приоритетов.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Конструктор `new Promise` выполняется **синхронно**.

Таким образом сначала выводится

```
console.log('Создание промиса');
```

Затем

```
console.log('Конец скрипта');
```

Далее выполняется микротаск и выводится

```
console.log('Обработка промиса');
```

И далее выполняется следующая задача запланированная с помощью `setTimeout`

```
console.log('Таймаут');
```

Comment: Большое спасибо за разъяснение. Если синхронно, тогда все правильно)